# how to retrieve custom fields on taxonomy page?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the "advanced custom fields" plugin and need to have it so that a custom field is pulled in for the category pages.  I can get these to come in on pages, but the category pages are giving me a lot of trouble... 'video' is the name of the custom field I want to pull in.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
 <?php echo get_field('video', 'clear-creek'.$wp_query->queried_object->term-4); ?>
```

or just a standard version like this which works on the regualar pages...

```
                                 <?php the_field('video'); ?>
```

but it's not working... can someone please help steer me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a category's archive page, you would use this:

```
<?php echo get_field('video', 'category_'.get_query_var('cat')) ?>
```

If you are on a custom taxonomy instead, you would use this:

```
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
echo get_field('video', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id); ?>
```

This will dynamically get the taxonomy's slug and ID, and build out your get_field based on that information.